# Multiple sorting conditions in DolphinDB

Tags: sorting, conditional-statements, dolphindb

Suppose I have a table as follows:

```
id=`A`B`A`B`B`B`A
item= 10 1 1 3 5 10 6
t=table(id,item)

id item
-- ----
A  10  
B  1   
A  1   
B  3   
B  5   
B  10  
A  6
```

For example, I want to sort the table with two conditions: first, by the most commonly occurring item in column **item**, then by the highest number in column **item**.

How can I sort like this:

```
id  item
--- ----
A   10
B   10
A   1
B   1
A   6
B   5
B   3
```

Is there any way to go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
t1=table(id,item);
update t1 set count=count(item) context by item;
select * from t1 order by count desc,  item desc;
```